# Android: WebView shouldInterceptRequest not adding RequestProperties in the WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am intercepting requests from the webview using shouldInterceptRequest

below is my code for returning my WebResourceResponse

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static WebResourceResponse handleRequestViaUrlOnly(WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest){
        String url = webResourceRequest.getUrl().toString();
        Log.i("intercepting req....!!!", url);
        String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Sample-Header", "hello");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            return new WebResourceResponse(mime, "UTF-8", conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I call this method inside my CustomWebViewClient

```
class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return handleRequestViaUrlOnly(request);
    }
}
```

However, when I check the Request Headers from the WebView remote debugger in chrome://inspect/#devices.

The additional RequestProperty that I added is not present.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Sample-Header", "hello");
```

The Sample-Header is not present in the Request Headers in the WebView.

Am I missing something? I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Dose it goes in IO exception block?

Comment: nope it doesn't but calling this new URL(url).openConnection() requires catching the IOException.

Comment: Just post the complete code of calling this method?

Comment: This is my complete code in intercepting url requests.

Comment: handleRequestViaUrlOnly called from where that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136321/discussion-between-anurag-singh-and-aaron).

Comment: WebResourceRequest request , The headers are present .

please print and check for this value
Log.d(TAG,"shouldInterceptRequest request "+request.getRequestHeaders());

Comment: @surya yes the headers are present when I log them, but in the webview, the headers are not present

Comment: This [works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66358447/192373). Maybe, you are below LOLLIPOP and the deprecated variant of the `shouldInterceptRequest` method is actually being invoked? Maybe, you catch an IOException and your `handleRequestViaUrlOnly()` returns **null**?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that when you are passing `conn.getInputStream()` it gives only data. Response headers could be extracted by `conn.getHeaderFields()`. Also you will not be able to get your extra header back unless server supports it and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) not involved. Here is `wireshark` output of the connection

```
GET /~fdc/sample.html HTTP/1.1
Sample-Header: hello
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1; Android SDK built for x86_64 Build/NPF26K)
Host: www.columbia.edu
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 09:06:58 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Apr 2004 15:52:25 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 8664
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

As you can see there is no `Sample-Header: hello` header in response.

Here is the simple code that will construct `WebResourceResponse` headers from response and append your custom header to it:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    private Map<String, String> convertResponseHeaders(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
        Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        responseHeaders.put("Sample-Header", "hello");

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> item : headers.entrySet()) {
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String headerVal : item.getValue()) {
                values.add(headerVal);
            }
            String value = StringUtil.join(values, ",");
            Log.e(TAG, "processRequest: " + item.getKey() + " : " + value);

            responseHeaders.put(item.getKey(), value);
        }

        return responseHeaders;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        final String method = request.getMethod();
        final String url = request.getUrl().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "processRequest: " + url + " method " + method);
        String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(method);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Sample-Header", "hello");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = convertResponseHeaders(conn.getHeaderFields());

            responseHeaders.put("Sample-Header", "hello");

            return new WebResourceResponse(
                    mime,
                    conn.getContentEncoding(),
                    conn.getResponseCode(),
                    conn.getResponseMessage(),
                    responseHeaders,
                    conn.getInputStream()
                    );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "shouldInterceptRequest: " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: I also have a code like this, yes I get the response headers and my problem is the request headers. I cannot add request headers to my webview.  also if I log the request headers after adding one, I get them on the logs, however when it reaches the webview it is not present,

Comment: So you are trying to modify webResourceReqest and what that change to be reflected on the javascript side in the webview?