# How to update request header in WebView

Tags: android, webview, http-headers

I'm trying to access a URL from android WebView. While loading the URL i inspected through chrome that one header value is null (See the following image).

[image]

My question is, i want to update the Origin value. How can i do it?

**Note:** If Origin has null value only i've to update other wise i've to load as it is

Comment: Can you please add some code how you loading URL in Webview?

Comment: Check with answers in this thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android

Comment: I tried already but i'm unable to update the header

Answer (score 3):

For change request header you can use hashmap and add header key-value pairs

```
WebView web = findViewById(R.id.webView);

private Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
    Map <String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    extraHeaders.put("Authorization", "Bearer"); 
    return headers;
}
```

And next step need to create WebViewClient:

```
private WebViewClient getWebViewClient() {
    return new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString(), getHeaders());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url, getHeaders());
        return true;
    }
};
}
```

Add WebViewClient to your WebView:

```
web.setWebViewClient(getWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Hi Alireza, Thank you for help. But it's not working :-(

Comment: Hi Bahu, your welcome, I will hope you can find your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });




    HashMap<String, String> headers=new HashMap<>();

    webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com",headers);
```

Comment: Let me know the issue as I am doing the same its work well at my end

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `WebViewClient` and override the `shouldInterceptRequest()` method. If you target API 21 and higher, this will be

```kotlin
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse?
```

Inside, you will open an HTTPS connection:

```kotlin
val requestUrl = request.url!!.toString()
val httpsUrl = URL(requestUrl)
val conn: HttpsURLConnection = httpsUrl.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
for ((key, value) in request.requestHeaders) {
  conn.addRequestProperty(key, value)
}
```

now you have chance to add new headers or modify the existing ones, e.g.

```kotlin
conn.setRequestProperty("ORIGIN", "https://stackoverflow.com")
```

when your request is all set, you can wrap the results in a fresh **WebResourceResponse**:

```kotlin
return WebResourceResponse(
  conn.contentType.substringBefore(";"), 
  conn.contentType.substringAfter("charset=", "UTF-8"), 
  conn.inputStream)
```

a typical `conn.contentType` is `"text/html; charset=UTF-8"`. You may add more resilient parsing, or simply use the hardcoded values if you know them.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide additional http headers to webview using

> public void loadUrl (String url, 
>                   Map additionalHttpHeaders)
>
> additionalHttpHeaders Map: the additional headers to be used in the
>   HTTP request for this URL, specified as a map from name to value. Note
>   that if this map contains any of the headers that are set by default
>   by this WebView, such as those controlling caching, accept types or
>   the User-Agent, their values may be overridden by this WebView's
>   defaults.

In your case origin is overridden by web view default http headers.